# can we enable metrics-listener for keycloak, not via GUI but from cli scripts ? having keycloack from codecentric repo

Tags: keycloak, prometheus, metrics, prometheus-operator

Keycloak version: 8.2.2 from codecentric

I copied keycloak-metrics-spi-2.5.0.jar to path -/opt/jboss/keycloak/standalone/deployments/ inside pod

and after deployement saw keycloak-metrics-spi-2.5.0.jar.deployed

logs of keycloak for metrics spi:

20:58:04,519 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.microprofile.metrics.smallrye] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 50) WFLYMETRICS0001: Activating Eclipse MicroProfile Metrics Subsystem
20:58:05,342 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-1) WFLYSRV0027: Starting deployment of "keycloak-metrics-spi-2.5.0.jar" (runtime-name: "keycloak-metrics-spi-2.5.0.jar")
20:58:05,913 INFO  [org.keycloak.subsystem.server.extension.KeycloakProviderDeploymentProcessor] (MSC service thread 1-1) Deploying Keycloak provider: keycloak-metrics-spi-2.5.0.jar
20:58:09,334 WARN  [org.keycloak.services] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 61) KC-SERVICES0047: metrics (org.jboss.aerogear.keycloak.metrics.MetricsEndpointFactory) is implementing the internal SPI realm-restapi-extension. This SPI is internal and may change without notice
20:58:09,337 WARN  [org.keycloak.services] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 61) KC-SERVICES0047: metrics-listener (org.jboss.aerogear.keycloak.metrics.MetricsEventListenerFactory) is implementing the internal SPI eventsListener. This SPI is internal and may change without notice
20:58:16,147 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 35) WFLYSRV0010: Deployed "keycloak-metrics-spi-2.5.0.jar" (runtime-name : "keycloak-metrics-spi-2.5.0.jar")

I added below line in pre-scripts, and observed metrics-event listener is not comming, though can be seen in siggestions,

add metrics listener

/subsystem=keycloak-server/spi=eventsListener/provider=metrics-listener:add(enabled=true)

Expecting is to have metrics-listener on GUI, dynamically not by manually adding it on GUI
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ExI3B.png)

can some one help here please ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use Keycloak [API](https://www.keycloak.org/docs-api/21.0.1/rest-api/index.html) to do this

```
PUT /auth/admin/realms/test/events/config HTTP/1.1
Content-Type: application/json
Authorization: Bearer <token>
Host: auth.localhost

{
    "eventsListeners": [
            "metrics-listener"
    ]
}
```

You can generate the bearer token using following API

```
POST /auth/realms/master/protocol/openid-connect/token?= HTTP/1.1
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Host: auth.localhost
Content-Length: 69

grant_type=password&username=admin&password=admin&client_id=admin-cli
```